# Compare date from sql (longtext) by an integer from php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

On my project i have wordpress custom field data from mysql :

```
---------------------------------------------------
id    | post_id   |   meta_key  |   meta_value 
---------------------------------------------------
1     | 200       |   age_min   |   5    
2     | 200       |   age_max   |   8   
3     | 399       |   ...       |   ...
```

My table structure

```
id => aut_increment 
meta_key => varchar(255)
meta_value => longtext
```

From my sql script i have to find childs between 'age_min and age_max' and childs number :

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID 
        , a.meta_value as nbrmin, b.meta_value as nbr_enfants_min , c.meta_value as age_min, d.meta_value as age_max

        FROM `6288gjvs_posts` as p 
        LEFT JOIN 6288gjvs_postmeta as a ON a.post_id = p.ID 
        LEFT JOIN 6288gjvs_postmeta as b ON b.post_id = p.ID 
        LEFT JOIN 6288gjvs_postmeta as c ON c.post_id = p.ID 
        LEFT JOIN 6288gjvs_postmeta as d ON d.post_id = p.ID 
        WHERE p.post_type = 'product' AND post_status = 'publish' 

        AND a.meta_key = 'childs_min_number' 
        AND a.meta_value <= 2

        AND b.meta_key = 'childs_max_number' 
        AND b.meta_value >= 2

        AND c.meta_key = 'age_min' 
        AND c.meta_value = 1

        AND d.meta_key = 'age_max' 
        AND d.meta_value >= 10
```

When i launch this query, this not working properly, because meta_value type is a longtext and my php variables ( $this->age_min, $this->age_max ) are integers, so i cannot compare those 2 different type ?

I tried to convert like this with no luck :

```
... CONVERT(a.meta_value, DECIMAL) ...
```

as mentioned from this site : [Mysql conversion functions](http://www.geeksengine.com/database/single-row-functions/conversion-functions.php#p1-5)

Anyone can help me please ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgive me if I'm wrong but shouldn't it be `AND b.meta_value >= {$this->age_max}`?

Comment: DAMN IT, 17 SECONDS LATE

Comment: You'r in right, i made an edit on my question, i have to search between childs ages and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to convert types
I think the error is in line 
`AND a.meta_value <= {$this->age_min}`

should not it be `AND a.meta_value >= {$this->age_min}`?

Comment: Thank you all, you are in right i changed the a.meta_value but still not working ,  i edited the question for my real sql query ( not working :p)

Comment: I don't see any errors in sql query, can you run in at mysql server, not from php?

Comment: Hey,
I am a bad tester the mistake 'a.meta_value >= {$this->age_min}' is the responsible of this crime.
Thank you for you help guys.
I just want to have your confirmation : i should not convert the longtext to decimal ? really ?

Comment: I don't remember cases when I store only integer in text, anyway when you make text column to store there everything: text, integer, datetime then to make comparisons with this column it is enough to surround with quotes, so `a.meta_value = '5' AND b.meta_value = 'test' AND c.meta_value = '2016-04-26'`